# Access DropDownList.SelectedIndex in DataList.ItemCreatedCommand (EventBubbling or other solutions)

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, event-bubbling

How am I to bubble the event caused when itemIndex is changed in a dropdownlist - so that I can use the itemindex-value in my ItemCreatedCommand-function?

A solution is found at:

http://209.85.129.132/search?q=cache:cYDzeE8Swf0J:authors.aspalliance.com/hmcheung/Articles/030331/Default.aspx+dropdownlist+datalist+selectedindex&hl=no&ct=clnk&cd=11&gl=no&client=firefox-a

- But this is in VB.net, and I don't "speak" VB.net well enough to replicate this to C#.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible as far as I've found out - must be bubbled up to ItemCommand, and not ItemCreated-command. Thus, leaving you with handling the event, and getting the senders.parent, which is the datalistitem.